AndroidStudio debugger cannot debug armeabi-v7a devices
Android Studio Koala Feature Drop | 2024.1.2 
NDK 26.1.10909125
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.androiddebug'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.androiddebug"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags '-std=c++11'
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
            version '3.22.1'
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation libs.appcompat
    implementation libs.material
    implementation libs.constraintlayout
    testImplementation libs.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.ext.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.espresso.core
}

I used this version of Android Studio create a sample native project, nothing changed, can be successfully compiled, but I use armeabi-v7a device debugging, the Debug windows just show that
"lost connection
Process finished with exit code 0"
arm64-v8a device is no problem, i can debug normally
